# Sending data from form to POST request in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, post

I want to make a POST request using Angular. I am using ng-submit to submit the form to the controller where I access the factory to make the request using:

```
$http.post('/droplets', data)
```

I need the data from the form fields to put in the "data" variable above to send to my API but I can't work out how to do this when it is more than one field. How is this done?

Comment: why do you not just give the form `action="/droplets" method="post"` and let it submit itself? `ng-submit` will still be triggered

Comment: I don't want a page refresh. I want to use AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$http({
        url: '/droplets',
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({application:app, from:data1, to:data2}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
};
```

Ref:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain: data: JSON.stringify({application:app, from:data1, to:data2})? I'm not sure what should go in the parentheses.

Comment: request like "{"application":"appname","from":"test","to":"test"}"

Comment: I'm still not clear. What do the "from:" and "to:" refer to?

Comment: from and to are key of test and test,see above json